# Adding target/action for custom UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone

So I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.  I have two cells, each in their own section.  Both have a UISegmentedControl in them with their own outlet/xib, etc.  Both rows show up fine in the simulator, but only the first cell (SortByTableViewCell) will have the action called when the UISegmentedControl is pressed.  In the second cell, the UISegmentedControl does not crash the app, but it also does not call its selector.  Is there something obvious that I am missing?  Thanks!

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSUInteger section = [indexPath section];
    NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
    if (section == 0) {
        static NSString *SortByCellIdentifier = @"SortByCellIdentifier";
        SortByTableViewCell *cell = (SortByTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:SortByCellIdentifier];
        [cell.SortBySegmentedControl addTarget:self action:@selector(SortBySegmentedControlPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
        if (cell == nil) {
            NSArray *nibObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SortByTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
            for (id currentObject in nibObjects) {
                if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[SortByTableViewCell class]]) {
                    cell = (SortByTableViewCell *)currentObject;
                }
            }
        }
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        return cell;
    }
    else {

            static NSString *ConditionCellIdentifier = @"ConditionCellIdentifier";
            ConditionTableViewCell *cell = (ConditionTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:ConditionCellIdentifier];
            [cell.ConditionSegmentedControl addTarget:self action:@selector(ConditionSegmentedControlPressed:) forControlEvents:
             UIControlEventValueChanged];
            if (cell == nil) {
                NSArray *nibObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ConditionTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
                for (id currentObject in nibObjects) {
                    if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[ConditionTableViewCell class]]) {
                        cell = (ConditionTableViewCell *)currentObject;
                    }
                }
            }
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        return cell;
       }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why setting the addTarget before your cell initialization?
Try with:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
NSUInteger section = [indexPath section];
NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
if (section == 0) {
    static NSString *SortByCellIdentifier = @"SortByCellIdentifier";
    SortByTableViewCell *cell = (SortByTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:SortByCellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        NSArray *nibObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SortByTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
        for (id currentObject in nibObjects) {
            if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[SortByTableViewCell class]]) {
                cell = (SortByTableViewCell *)currentObject;
            }
        }
    }
    [cell.SortBySegmentedControl addTarget:self action:@selector(SortBySegmentedControlPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    return cell;
}
else {

        static NSString *ConditionCellIdentifier = @"ConditionCellIdentifier";
        ConditionTableViewCell *cell = (ConditionTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:ConditionCellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil) {
            NSArray *nibObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ConditionTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
            for (id currentObject in nibObjects) {
                if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[ConditionTableViewCell class]]) {
                    cell = (ConditionTableViewCell *)currentObject;
                }
            }
        }
        [cell.ConditionSegmentedControl addTarget:self action:@selector(ConditionSegmentedControlPressed:) forControlEvents:
         UIControlEventValueChanged];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    return cell;
   }
```

Hope it's solve your problem.

Comment: you are effing awesome!  thanks!  i pull my hair out for these small things sometimes!  hopefully one day i'll remember them all!

Comment: In objective-c [nil doSomeStuff] doesn't return a NullPointerException like in Java. Just nothing is done. So in your code cell was nil then cell.ConditionSegmentedControl was nil so no target was added.

Comment: And please rename your ConditionSegmentedControl to conditionSegmentedControl. A property name can't begin with capital letter.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried removing the connection in Interface Builder and recreating it?